# Error: file 'home/user/values.yaml' seems to be a YAML file, but expected a gzipped archive

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress

I am trying to install Kube Prometheus Stack using helm.

I have already setup ingress, so it needs to be running behind a proxy.

For that I have updated values of the chart by using below command.

```
helm show values prometheus-com/kube-prometheus-stack > values.yaml
```

I followed this [doc](https://grafana.com/tutorials/run-grafana-behind-a-proxy/) and changed configurations,

```
[server]
domain = example.com
```

Now I am trying to install using below command.

```
helm install monitoring ./values.yaml  -n monitoring
```

I have already created a namespace `monitoring`

I get below error on running above command.

```
Error: file '/home/user/values.yaml' seems to be a YAML file, but expected a gzipped archive
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your helm command should be something like this:

```
$ helm install <release-name> <registry-name>/<chart-name> --values ./values.yaml  -n monitoring
```

Comment: SO and Google don't seem to have clear answers for this question in 2023!
It will help if you can elaborate this with an example.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set the path to the values.

The helm install command is:

```
helm install -f myvalues.yaml <release_name> <path_to_chart_folder>
```

Example:

```
helm install -f myvalues.yaml myredis ./redis
```

If you don't use the '-f' parameter you're just setting the path to the chart folder which shouldn't be a yaml but at least a gzipped archive!

Your install should be something like this:

```
helm install -f ./values.yaml  -n monitoring monitoring . //where the '.' is the path of the Chart folder
```